# How to create custom SQL Propel Task for Symfony Task?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, propel

I want to insert data into a Table with a for-loop. 
First of all I have create a Symfony Task with:

```
symfony generate:task namespace:MyTask
```

now I'm trying to generate a propel sql task that I can call into my Symfony Task so that when I call :

```
symfony namespaceMyTask
```

it insert an amount of `for(i=10; i < 30; i++)` Data into a Table.

How can I create a custom propel task that can be call into a symfony task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the doc under "[Executing a Task inside a Task](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/13-Leveraging-the-Power-of-the-Command-Line#chapter_13_executing_a_task_inside_a_task)".

```
$this->runTask('namespaceMyTask');
```

Comment: Merci! but that's great! but i miss the way to create an Own Propel Task! or it's not possible?

Comment: You can't create a "propel task", propel is the orm not the framework. You have to create a symfony task that will use propel to do what ever you want.